# Что возвращает функция scandir() в PHP?

Tags: php

Функция scandir() возвращает массив типа:

```
Array
(
    [0] => .
    [1] => ..
    [2] => indian.jpg
)
```

Что такое элементы [0] и [1]?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

0 - ссылка на текущую директорию.
1 - ссылка на родительскую директорию.

Comment: то то и оно